# MAGMI: Do not overwrite value without using Import Limiter

Tags: magento, magmi

I am using the MAGMI sku finder to map one of my columns to the SKU. The column I am mapping is called `ordernumber`.

This works fine, the only problem is that when I import products now, it overwrites the `ordernumber` as well.

I can not use the MAGMI import limiter and exclude the `ordernumber` becasue it is used as the mandatory SKU. Is there any other way to NOT import the `ordernumber` column, but the rest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you import new product you can use the `"create new items only, skip new once"` when start importing.

Otherwise you can just remove `"ordernumber"` column form product import csv.

Comment: I can not remove it, because it is used by the sku finder MAGMI plugin. The products already exist, so I can not use the option you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the "create new items only, skip new once" option for only update existing one items ?

Comment: Yes I did, this overwrites the ordernumber column, which I do not want.